# How to auto fit the row height and width in ext.js Panel?

Tags: css, extjs

I have extended java script Panel with me that contains a a few columns. The data inside the column is received from the server. Some times the data from the server for each column is large and it does not fit inside the row.

Here is the code for the same:

```
Ext.define('DataDetailsGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    requires: [
        'DataStore'
    ],
    id: 'DataDetailsGrid',
    xtype: 'grid',
    margin: "20 20 20 20",
    nestedView: false,
    title: 'Student information',
    store: 'DataStore',
    frame: true,
    flex: 1,
    viewConfig : { 
        deferEmptyText: false,
        emptyText: 'No data Available'
    },
    columns: [
        { text: 'Id', flex: 0.5, dataIndex: 'id' },
        { text: 'Student name', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'student_name' },
        { text: 'Time Stamp', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'requestTimeStamp' },
        { text: 'email Id', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'emailId' },
        { text: 'About Students', flex: 4, dataIndex: 'response' },
    ]
});
```

The issue is with **About Students** which can be about 500 characters sometimes. This is not getting accommodated inside the given row.

Comment: Maybe put About Students in [rowexpander](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.RowExpander)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this css code for wrap Adout Students Data.
Check fiddle:https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1i3g

```
.x-grid-cell-inner {
 white-space: initial;
}
```

Comment: How to do so ? Where can i add css in this

Comment: You need to create a css file and add there.Please check fiddle

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add the following line to your `column`'s definition

```
cellWrap: true
```

Check this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1i5o
. I've taken the liberty of forking Ajay Thakur's fiddle.

So, in your case, change your offending code to the following line:

```
{ text: 'About Students', flex: 4, dataIndex: 'response', cellWrap: true }
```